# "Mental state" vs. "mental status"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, difference, terminology

What is the difference between *mental state* and *mental status*?

For example:

> The evaluation/diagnosis was based on my **mental state (status?)**

Google and Wikipedia appear to suggest both terms are in use. There is a medical examination called the [**mental status examination**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_status_examination). There is also a Wiki page on [**mental state**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_state).

Comment: Also see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12958/status-vs-state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a doctor, nor do I play one on TV, so I'm not going to be playing light with real medical terms...

Your mental status was based on an evaluation of your mental state.

The 'status' is a 'quantifiable' measurement; a rubber stamp of what the evaluation determined.

Your status could be...
- Fine.
- A bit odd.
- Talks to himself.
- Barking mad.
- Completely hatstand.

based on your mental state when interviewed...
- completely rational
- muttering & staring at the floor
- swinging from the light-shade
- wearing your underpants on your head, pencils up your nose & saying "Wibble".

Comment: +1 for the distinction.  I'd agree that the "status" is a label indicating or categorizing "state".

Answer (score 3):

**Mental state** has a lot of definitions and usages, and the meaning can vary.  [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_state) is as good as any:

> ...a mental state is a kind of hypothetical state that corresponds to thinking and feeling, and consists of a conglomeration of mental representations and propositional attitudes.

Additional from [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mental+state):

> ...a mental condition in which the qualities of a state are relatively constant even though the state itself may be dynamic.

In other words, "mental state" is a subjective description of a general "internal" state of mind that endures for some period of time, rather than a momentary condition.

**Mental status** is an objective quantification or assessment of indicators of the person's mental state at a particular time.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware they both mean the same thing and can be used interchangeably. The term 'mental state' is older and is generally used more frequently than 'mental status', although in the last twenty years in the USA both terms are used at about the same frequency [(Ngram)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mental%20status%2Cmental%20state&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmental%20status%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmental%20state%3B%2Cc0). 'Mental status' tends to be used more frequently by medical or psychological professionals, whereas 'mental state' is more frequently used by the general public.